# SAPUI5 Refer to an ID in another fragment

Tags: javascript, xml, user-interface, frontend, sapui5

Is there a way to refer to an ID in another fragment?

Fragment 1: SmartFilterBar
Fragment 2: SmartTable

I want to refer the ID of the SmartFilterBar from inside my SmartTable Fragment.

Comment: `sap.ui.getCore().byId("controlId");`

Comment: I mean right from the XML view. Something like this:
<SmartTable smartFilterId="smartFilterFragment--smartFilter" />

Comment: It would be interesting to know why you want to do that. Maybe there is an underlying problem which is much easier to solve.